# Can the argument of delete[] operator point to non-first element of an array?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

The question is as above; if I have, for example, `int* ptr = new int[10]` and after some operations with data `ptr` is set to, say, 2nd, 3rd 5th or last element, will the call `delete[] ptr` be the correct one? Can't find it in the manual.

Comment: Here's the reference: [operator delete\[\]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/). The `ptr` parameter to `delete []` must either be a pointer previously returned by `new []` or the NULL pointer.

Comment: No, you have to delete with the original address. Internally, a common implementation of `new[]` puts the size of the array just before the allocated memory -- so `delete[]` (looking just behind the address you give it) would look at the wrong part of memory for the array size, causing havoc :-)

Comment: Thank you :) So it works as I expected. I only couldn't find a formal record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the argument passed to the `delete[]` operator must point to the same address that was returned by `new[]`

(Assuming you haven't overloaded `delete[]` and `new[]` to do something crazy)

Answer (score 2):

From the C++ reference manual [delete[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete%5b%5d/): *Notice that an invalid value of ptr causes undefined behaviour.*
Because of this it is not recommended to manipulate the pointer to your allocated memory directly!

Answer (score 2):

> Can't find it in the manual

C++11 3.7.4.2/3 says

> behavior is undefined if the value supplied to operator `delete[](void*)` in the standard library is not one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either `operator new[](std::size_t)` or `operator new[](std::size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)` in the standard library